# MVC C# Recalculate user inputs without going to the controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I would like to be able to let the user enter dollar amounts (or any number) and then display calculations based on that number "on the fly" without going back to the controller (update totals as the inputs change).

Here is a simple example:

The Model:

```
using System;

namespace SandboxJScalc.Models
{
    public class CommonInfo
    {
        public decimal Amount1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount2 { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model SandboxJScalc.Models.CommonInfo
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Sandbox JS Calc</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Sandbox JS Calc</h1>
    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Amount 1 :</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount1,
                         new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "recalc()" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount 2 :</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount2,
                         new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "recalc()" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Amount :</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript">
       function recalc()
       {
           m.TotalAmount = m.Amount1 + m.Amount2;
       }
</script>
```

How can I make it call "recalc" and display the updated total every time the user changes Amount1 or Amount2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the other jquery events like mouseout  event and get the calculated value. Then put post your form back to controller. Another way is use Ajax helper in mvc to call method

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sample Call", "Home", "Home", new AjaxOptions  
{  
   UpdateTargetId = "divmain",  
   OnBegin = "fnOnBegin",  
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
   HttpMethod = "GET",  
   LoadingElementId = "imgloader",  
   OnSuccess= "fnSuccess",  
   Confirm="Do you want to get all data ?????"  
}
, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Comment: @Charlie I have update the ans with the sample code where    OnBegin = "fnOnBegin",  
onbegin gets called before post call.

Comment: How would you modify ```@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount1, new { @class = "{number: true}  small-input", onblur = "recalc()" }) ``` to make use of this?  Would the recalc function be in the controller or can it be done in the cshtml?

Comment: @RahulShukla Sorry but this still doesn't answer my question.  I looked at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXS-PU0uFRI but can't make that work either.

Comment: @MarkRLV please follow this article for the MVC ajax helper usage  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/

Comment: @RahulShukla I figured it out.  Thank you for giving me the pointers in the right direction.  My solution is here: https://github.com/MarkRLV/SandboxJScalc